# Ban deleting rows that are used in other tables laravel

Tags: sql, laravel-5.4

so i have two tables:

```
Schema::create('groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('course_id');
            $table->timestamp('start_date')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('end_date')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

when editing course i have a function to delete it. However, i want to have a feature that it would not allow to delete a course row, it its id is used in groups table. Should this be done in SQL or laravel has some magic feature? And how i could display the error properly?

Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  Most support 'enforcing referential integrity' which is what I think you're looking for.

Comment: @JeffUK, im using mariadb

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/foreign-keys/

Comment: @JRLambert, thanks. This is what i was looking for.